# Help to find cubics with square discriminant

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

If the discriminant $b^2-4c$ of the quadratic $x^2 + bx + c$ is a square then it factors. For every discriminant $d^2$ we have can parametrize them all $(b,c) = (d + 2 h,h(d+h))$. **edit** I realized now that the quadratic case is trivial because it the discriminant is a square iff it factors, so the two variable parametrization is $(x-a)(x-b)$ so it might not represent what is happening with the cubic.

I was hoping to do a similar parametrization for the cubics $x^3 - ax + b$ with square discriminant $4a^3 - 27b^2 = d^2$ but factoring in the Eisenstein integers does not seem to make the problem any easier.

Are there any other promising approaches I could try?

---

I noticed the problem is simple when $d=0$. In that case we have $a = 3 m^2$, $b = 2 m^3$. Also when $d = b$ we also get a simple parametrization, $a = 7m^2$, $b = 7m^3$ but I don't think these will help to get the general case.

Comment: By considering polynomials of the form $x^3-3ax+2b$ (assuming you're working over the rationals) the discriminant takes the nice form $\delta^2=b^2-a^3$

Comment: @quanta:  Actually I had a typo at first, so there's really a cube in there

Comment: This is a good idea! We are left with $$(\delta-b)(\delta+b)=a^3$$ which may be possible to work with.

Comment: I think that $\text{gcd}(\delta-b,\delta+b)= (1\text{ or }2) \cdot \text{gcd}(\delta,b)$.

Comment: @Quanta:  Yeah.  It's $1$ if $b,\delta$ have different parity (odd/even) and $2$ if it's the same.  When working with Diophantine equations, you can simplify things a bit by considering the "nontrivial" solutions:  no variable is zero and all are relatively coprime.  All other solutions can then be constructed from those.

Comment: @Riley, I know you can do coprime for homogeneous ones but when the variables have different exponents is it still possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equation like $4a^3−27b^2=d^2$ for fixed $d$ defines a curve in the plane with coordinates $a,b$. It can be parametrised by rational functions if and only if it is singular, which is the case in your examples $d = 0$ and $d = b$. If not, it can be completed to an [elliptic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), which can not be parametrised by rational functions.

Comment: doetoe, That is really interesting! Thanks for this result. I wonder if it would be possible to characterize all the $d$ that make this form singular?

Comment: Which I think would be $6a^2 = d \frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}a} $, $27b = -d \frac{\mathrm{d}d}{\mathrm{d}b} $.

Answer (score 2):

If you factor in the Eisenstein integers, you can get a parametrization though it's a bit messy.

Write $b + 3\sqrt{-3}d = b + 3d(2j+1) = (b+3d)+(3d)j = 2u$, so you can write $a^3 = u \bar{u}$.
Since $u \bar{u}$ must be a cube, $u$ has to factor into bunches of product of primes of the form $p^3$ or $p^2 \bar{p}$, so you can find Eisenstein integers $v$ and $w$ such that $u = v^3w^2\bar{w}$ (though this decomposition is generally not unique)

This parametrization gives you $a = vw\bar{v}\bar{w}$ and $(b+3d)+(3d)j = 2v^3w^2\bar{w}$.
If you want to get integer parameters, then you will have 4 parameters, and in order to get the equations for $b$ and $d$ you have to expand the product $v^3w^2\bar{w}$ to get its integer components, and then solve the system for $b$ and $d$.

Answer (score 2):

I would not focus on parametrization as such. Instead, note that $4 a^3 = d^2 + 27 b^2.$ This gives an easily stated restriction on the prime factorization of $a.$ It is necessary and sufficient that $a \geq 0$ and, whenever any prime $p | a$ and $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ then the exponent of $p$ must be even. So $a = 2$ or $a = 5$ or $a=10$ are impossible. Without the cube, there would be a restriction on the prime 3 as well, but it turns out not to matter because you have $a^3.$ Without the $4$ in $4a^3,$ there would be a competition between $d^2 + 27 b^2$ and the other forms in the genus, $4 u^2 \pm 2 u v + 7 v^2.$ But
$$ 
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  4 & 0 \\
  1 & 1  
\end{array} 
  \right) 
\; \cdot \; 
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 27  
\end{array} 
  \right) 
\; \cdot \;
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  4 & 1 \\
  0 &  1  
\end{array} 
  \right) =  \; \;\; \; 
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  16 & 4 \\
  4 & 28  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
 $$

Now, try $a = 4 = 2^2,$ so the exponent on 2 is even, you get $4a^3 = 256,$ and you get $d = 16, b = 0,$ which seems too easy. i will put some more below, maybe skip squares... But, given a legal $a$ as described, the number of pairs $d,b$ is finite.

$$a = 1,4a^3 = 4, ( d = \pm 2, b = 0), $$
$$a = 3, 4a^3 = 108, ( d = \pm 9, b = \pm 1), ( d = 0, b = \pm 2), $$
 $$a = 7, 4a^3 = 1372, ( d = \pm 20, b = \pm 6), ( d = \pm 7, b = \pm 7), $$
  $$a = 12, 4a^3 = 6912, ( d = \pm 72, b = \pm 8), ( d = 0, b = \pm 16), $$
 $$a = 13, 4a^3 = 8788, ( d = \pm 70, b = \pm 12), ( d = \pm 65, b = \pm 13). $$

Well, given all possible representations $a = s^2 + s t + t^2,$ one may construct all $d,b,$ an annoying task unless $a$ is prime with $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ This is, essentially, what factoring in the Eisenstein integers will give you.

Actually, that last bit was needlessly pessimistic. With a little special treatment of the primes 2,3, I can see how to create all possible representations of $a = j^2 + 3 k^2,$ create all possible representations of $4a^3 = m^2 + 3 n^2,$ then just keep the ones when $3 | n.$ Rather involved but easy enough to program.

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant of an irreducible cubic is a square if and only if it is a cyclic cubic, that is, if and only if its Galois group is the cyclic group of order $3$. There are tabulations in the literature of all cyclic cubics with discriminant less than $n$, for various values of $n$. These can be found by web-searching the phrase "cyclic cubic" (or "abelian cubic", which amounts to the same thing, since if the Galois group isn't the cyclic group of order $3$, it must be the symmetric group on three letters, which group is not abelian).

Answer (score 0):

The [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Discriminant%5B%20x%5E3%20-%20a%20x%20%2B%20b%2C%20x%5D) of the cubic $x^3 - a x + b$ is $4 a^3 - 27 b^2$ and we are looking for triplets $(a,b,c)$ satisfying

$$4 a^3 = 27 b^2 + c^2= F(b,c)$$ or
$$a = 27 \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{c}{2 a}\right)^2$$

so we can parametrize rational solutions $(a,b,c)$ by

\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& F(u,v) \\
b &=& 2 u F(u,v) \\
c &=& 2 v F(u,v)
\end{eqnarray}

where $F(u,v) = 27 u^2 + v^2$. Therefore, the reduced cubics with square discriminant are  of the form

$$P(x,u,v)=x^3 - (27 u^2 + v^2) x + 2 u(27 u^2 + v^2)$$

and the general cubics with square discriminant( $\Delta = (2 v(27 u^2 + v^2))^2$ ) are of the form

$$P(x+w, u,v) = x^3 + 3 w x^2 + (3 w^2 -(27 u^2 + v^2))x + ( w^3 - (27 u^2 + v^2) w + 2u ( 27 u^2 + v^2))$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Reduced cubics with square determinant can also be obtained as

$$x^3 - 3(u^2 - u v + v^2) x + (u^3 + v^3)$$
with discriminant $\Delta= 81(u-v)^2(u^2 - u v + v^2)^2$

It is not hard to check that we get all reduced cubics with rational coefficients and square discriminant in this way. This implies no such cubics have constant term $\pm 1$.